# Specifying the WM_CLASS of a program?

Tags: window-manager, wayland

I am using `wayland` based `swaywm` as my window manager. It uses the `WM_CLASS` property for the title of its *containers* (not sure if it is applicable only for X11 apps). It lets you group stuff, so that you can easily do scripting over a bunch of related windows.

However, the problem is that it is not uniform across applications. Sometimes you would see title case which is not nice if you have a `-` separated word like `Google-chrome`.

Can I control the `WMClass` of an application, so that I can at-least lowercase it?

Some `.desktop` files have an option that says `StartupWMClass`. How do I use that information while executing a command manually? I tried `StartupWMClass=code code` but that doesn't help.

Comment: Some apps, like `xterm` have a `-class` option just for that. gtk apps like chrome don't seem to have anything similar. But you can change the `WM_CLASS` property on an existing window with `xprop(1)`, though that may be too late in your case. You can also use a `LD_PRELOAD` hack, though it may be overkill (you may just as well fix your `wm` in its source & recompile).

Comment: Gtk applications have the `--class` option for this (see `man gtk-options`).

Comment: Thanks @mosvy, yes apparently chrome also complies with `--class` as mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks @StephenKitt, `--class` is nice; it would have been nice if there was a toolkit independent solution. For `code`, it is mentioned in `package.json` and that seems to be the standard for `electron` based apps.

Comment: Fine, sorry for the misinformation, then.

Comment: @mosvy, that is fine. I was not looking for a app specific solution, just wanted to know if it can be configured via environment options. If not, I might have to tweak the `wm` like you said! I will also explore `LD_PRELOAD`.

Comment: As `WM_CLASS` like the other window properties are set by the toolkit, there can't be any toolkit-indepent solution for the initial settings. Some window managers allow matching on other criteria than class, but I've no idea what `swaywm` does. But I'd assume you could change it in the source code, if it's an important feature for you.

Comment: @dirkt, thanks. I thought it could be read from the environment options (by overriding any other configuration). For example, `WM_CLASS="google-chrome" google-chrome`. Now I think most toolkit have their own convention for setting `WM_CLASS`.

Comment: As mentioned in the other answers, historically, all the early X toolkits supported `--class` (this commandline parsing automatically done when the application initializes). Then more modern toolkits were invented, their programmers chose to ignore the old conventions ("Linux must be made modern for the Desktop, users won't need command line options!"), and that's why we can't have nice things like conventions that work for all toolkits.